# coming to + infinitive

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

> We’re afraid of coming to grapple with words...

Is this sentence grammatical? I can somehow infer that it's related to a progressive action, like being afraid to become to grapple with words, in this case, but it sounds pretty artificial and undue.

Comment: It sounds like a bastardisation of the idiomatic  'We are afraid of [really] getting to grips with words...' to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct phrasing would be as follows:

**"We're afraid of grappling with words that are unfamiliar to us."**

Alternatively, it would also be proper to say,

**"We're afraid of having to grapple with words that are unfamiliar to us."**